# iOS 8.1.1 iPhone device is not regestering in Extract Target

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce1-app

I have used two devices for testing. But only iOS 7.0.4 device has registered in the extract target.  iOS 8.1.1 is not registered.

[I have followed the instructions given in here](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/journey-builder-for-apps/sdk-implementation/register-your-devices.html#ios)

Here is my Code on App Delegate

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        //


        [[ETPush pushManager]configureSDKWithAppID:@"16f943f6-c35c-42e3-bfe5-e58a6237503a" andAccessToken:@"kdhzwupv7jxqquwqewed9bms" withAnalytics:YES andLocationServices:NO andCloudPages:NO];

        // IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.X or 7.X
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 80000
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
        // Supports IOS SDK 8.X (i.e. XCode 6.X and up)
        // are we running on IOS8 and above?
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)]) {
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert
                                                                                     categories:nil];
            [[ETPush pushManager] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
            [[ETPush pushManager] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
        else {
            [[ETPush pushManager] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
        }
    #else
        // Supports IOS SDKs < 8.X (i.e. XCode 5.X or less)
        [[ETPush pushManager] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    #endif
    #else
        // IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET >= 8.X
        // Supports IOS SDK 8.X (i.e. XCode 6.X and up)
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert
                                                                                 categories:nil];
        [[ETPush pushManager] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[ETPush pushManager] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    #endif
        [[ETPush pushManager] shouldDisplayAlertViewIfPushReceived:YES];
        [[ETPush pushManager] applicationLaunchedWithOptions:launchOptions];

        //
    return YES;
    }

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [[ETPush pushManager] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        [[ETPush pushManager]
         applicationDidFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
    }

    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
        [[ETPush pushManager] handleNotification:userInfo
                             forApplicationState:application.applicationState];
    }
```

Since I am new to iOS , I cant justify with existing code correctly. If the iOS 7.0.4 device has registered in the saleseforce account. It will not recived any notifications sent from salesforce cloud.

Comment: Gihan you'll need to provide some more context of what you're trying to do and what isn't working. Or what instructions are unclear to you, or show code that you've written. Else the only thing we can do is guess what isn't working.

Comment: Thank You Samuel, and I have edited the question with my code base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the steps we have followed correct and the code provided by sales force also correct. Only mistake I have done is impatient than saleseforce. Extract Target is taking some times to get register a device on their account.Already what I have done is uninstall the app before send a notification, and installed it again. But the contact list always updated with previous Device ID. Now I have wait for some time till update the extract target with new device ID. Then added the device ID to contact list. Then sent the notification.Notifications successfully received.